# Basic CucumberJS and Zombie Use Case

Tags: javascript, zombie.js, cucumberjs

Good Day my fellow Comrades in Code:

I followed some vanilla set up examples for using zombie and cucumber. The basic problem is that I visit a site in the first step. Then, in the next step, the zombie browser is not aware of it any more. I have a very basic setup, so I am unsure what I could be missing.

Here is how I run the test, from the project home:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cucumber.js -r features/
```

Here is the cucumber file, very short:

```
Feature: Load up the web page

  Scenario: Go to the index page
    Given I go to the "" page
    Then I should see "Start"
```

Here are the two step definitions. As you can see, for sanity's sake, I am merely trying to access google:

```
assert = require('assert')

module.exports = function(){
  this.World = require(process.cwd() + "/features/support/world").World;

  this.Given(/^I go to the "([^"]*)" page$/, function (subpath, callback) {
    this.browser.visit("http://www.google.com", function(e,browser){
      //console.log(browser.html());
    });

    callback();
  });

  this.Then(/^I should see "([^"]*)"$/, function (arg1, callback) {
    console.log(this.browser.location.pathname);
    console.log(this.browser.html());
    callback();
  });
}
```

And here is the output when run:

```
./
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
.

1 scenario (1 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
```

If I uncomment the console.log in the first step, the output is the HTML from visiting google, a la:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"><head> <meta content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /> <title>Google</title>
```

Etc.

Here is my world.js setup. It's quite vanilla:

```
var zombie = require('zombie')
var World = function World(callback){
  this.browser = new zombie.Browser();
  callback();
};

module.exports.World = World;
```